# Find employee's manager and create a columns

Tags: mysql

My input table looks like this

| Employee | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| rahul | aria |
| aria | priya |
| priya | sheela |
| vasant | reema |
| reema | carol |
| guha | reeye |

This is the output I want

| Employee | Manager 1 | Manager 2 | Manager 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rahul | aria | priya | sheela |
| vasant | reema | carol |  |
| guha | reeya |  |  |

How can I achieve this? I tried until I can make it to the only manager, but not sure how to build columns as manager-employee relationship goes on

Comment: [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: What if there are more than 3 layers of management?

Comment: It should be Manager 4 and so on

Comment: You need in "Pivot" (search SO by this term accompanied by DBMS tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL hierarchy query to retrieve :

```
    with tabletest as 
(
select 
'rahul' employee , 'aria' as manager from dual
union 
select 
'aria' as employee, 'priya' as manager from dual
union 
select
'priya' as employee, 'sheela' as manager from dual
)

select level, a.employee, Sys_Connect_By_Path(a.manager,'/') as path from tabletest a
connect by prior a.employee = a.manager;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN8aK.png)

Comment: The tag is MySQL, connect is Oracle. PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [answer] [Help]